# How to query mongoDB with TEXT (no java code) from Java, REST forbidden by OPS

Tags: java, mongodb, request

I need a solution to parse a MongoDB shell query (or something close to) using Java...

I maintain a tool written in Java, used to move and transform data to and from different applications and tools.
I have been asked to implement something to query MongoDB... but am a total newbie in MongoDB, and... 
It's a mess: Ops decided to not allow the rest communication, and deploying new specific Java code for each demand is not an option.

I try for some days to find a generic solution to request MongoDB from Java, simply giving a "request text" (yes, something like SQL) in order to make the solution easily reusable and maintainable.

One not bad solution is to use Nashorn and write a MongoDB dedicated code/request to be run. I already made the script module, it works on simple request but becomes a real pain in case of complex multi-level requests, and my users are not developers.

The second trail is to find a "Java accessible" MongoDB method to parse a "MongoDB shell" request, whatever it is. I have some results in a case of "Document" like the request but found nothing concerning "pipelines" starting with "[" as a JSON array... I saw here that hacking the mongoShell was not such a good idea, and I agree.

Any fresh idea ?
Thanks

```
//----------------------------
// Nashorn script
// inputObject contains configuration data

var credential= MongoCredential.createCredential( inputObject.user, inputObject.baseName, inputObject.passWord.toCharArray() );
var mongoClient= null;
try
{
    mongoClient= new MongoClient( mongoServerList, java.util.Arrays.asList(credential) );
    var mongoBase= mongoClient.getDatabase( inputObject.baseName );

    var nbDocs= mongoBase.getCollection("messages_pnr").count();
print("nb docs= " + nbDocs );

    var resultingDocuments= mongoBase.getCollection("messages").aggregate   (   java.util.Arrays.asList (
            new Document("$match", new Document("version", 2))
        ,   new Document("$sort", new Document("_id", 1))
        ,   new Document("$limit", 5)
        ,   new Document("$project", new Document("_id", 0).append("identifier", "$identifier"))
    )   );

print("step 1");
    var it_resultingDocuments= resultingDocuments.iterator();
print("step 2");
        while( it_resultingDocuments.hasNext() )
        {
print("step 3");
            var currentResultingDocument= it_resultingDocuments.next();
            print( currentResultingDocument.toJson() );
        }
}
finally
{   if( mongoClient != null)
    {   mongoClient.close();
    }
}

//----------------------------------
// Java code for Document (found nothing for arrays)

        MongoClient mongoClient= null;
        try
        {   // cnx
            MongoCredential credential= MongoCredential.createCredential( this.getUser(), this.getBaseName(), this.getPassWord().toCharArray() );
            mongoClient= new MongoClient( this.getMongoServersList(), Arrays.asList(credential) );
            MongoDatabase mongoBase= mongoClient.getDatabase( this.getBaseName() );


long counter= 0;
            Document requestDocument=  Document.parse(mongoRequest);
            MongoCollection<Document> collection= mongoBase.getCollection("messages_pnr");
            AggregateIterable<Document> aggregate= collection.aggregate( Arrays.asList(requestDocument));
            MongoCursor<Document> cursorIterable= aggregate.iterator();
            while(cursorIterable.hasNext())
            {
                Document currentResult= cursorIterable.next();
                String currentResultAsString= currentResult.toJson();
counter++;
System.out.println(counter + " " + currentResultAsString);
                Utilities4Stream.copyFromByteArrayToOutputStreamsList(currentResultAsString.getBytes(), this.getResultOutputStreams());
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            if(mongoClient != null)
            {   mongoClient.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: So the users send JSON or javascript?

Comment: I still search for a generic solution, allowing the user to write request a in mongoshell or writing Nashorn script (but it's not usable by anybody).

Comment: But of course, any other kind of solution could be good, as far as it starts with a TEXT request, usedby Java to request MongoDB.

Comment: _found nothing for arrays_. Can you show an example for text request for this ? Are these multiple requests ? Have you tried iterating over JSONArray and parsing into individual document ?

Comment: Here's an example of what would be done (example in MongoShell)

Comment: db.message.aggregate(
  // Pipeline
  [
   // Stage 1
   {
    $match: {
     "name": {
      $eq: "ASF"
     }
    }
   },
   // Stage 2
   {
    $sort: {
     timestamp: 1
    }
   },
   // Stage 3
   {
    $project: {
     name: "$name",
     timestampMin: "$timestamp",
     timestampMax: "$timestampOk",
     duration: {
      $subtract: ["$timestampOk", "$timestamp"]
     }
    }
   },
   // Stage 4
   {
    $sort: {
     duration: -1
    }
   },
  ],
  // Options
 {
  cursor: {
   batchSize: 50
  }
 });

Comment: Am not sure to fully understand your question about iterating over multiple documents.... how could i execute the whole at the end ?

Comment: Could you  edit the post with the sample?

Comment: ??? sorry, i don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our dev support department found that people from "dbschema.com" wrote a jdbc compliant layer above mongo client, and it works fine for me !

> https://www.dbschema.com/mongodb-jdbc-driver.html